# Can a wild card be used as a skip card?

Tags: phase-10

Is it possible to play a wild card as a skip card? It makes a big difference when playing this game with two people. The rules state that you can play the wild card as any other card if I am correct.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [rules as written](https://service.mattel.com//instruction_sheets/DRJ53-Eng.pdf) a Wild Card may only be used in place of any number card, or as any color.  So without any rules variations you cannot use a Wild card as a Skip.

There is however a relatively common unofficial variant sometimes referred to as "Truly Wild" that does allow Wilds to be used as Skips.